# How to display bottom border of div's table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a Tic Tac Toe in JS, but at first I would like to create prototype of a board.

User will provide dimensions of a board (5x5 3x3 ect)

The problem is that I cannot set bottom border of the last #row

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong here? Thank you

```css
#mainContainer {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: solid black;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}

#mainContainer>div:last-child {
    border: solid black;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;

}

div.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

div.column {

    display: table-column;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border: solid black;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">1 1</div>
        <div class="column">1 2</div>
        <div class="column">1 3</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">2 1</div>
        <div class="column">2 2</div>
        <div class="column">2 3</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">3 1</div>
        <div class="column">3 2</div>
        <div class="column">3 3</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

In browser console I am able to see the border, but when launch a page, bottom border is hidden

Comment: dont try to do this by using a table. Use a mdoern solution like flexbox or CSS-Grid which have a few advantages espacially for full repsonsivness

Comment: @tacoshy: when the OP creates TicTacToe what responsivness advantages you mean? It has to be still 3x3 and it doesn't matter if using grid or table values, result will be the same.

Comment: @pavel espaciall for a game you want a responsivness that the board is smaller then the screen so you dont have to scroll. But as large as possible. a grid or a flexbox would allow to achieve that the easiest way. That you resize the board to fit the screen without overflow and have it as large as possible without blowing the aspect ratio.

Comment: @tacoshy in tictactoe we can use table values + vh/vw. But it isnt the question here.

Answer (score 4):

You've set `border-bottom-style: none` for all `.column`. Set `solid` for the last row.

```css
#mainContainer {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: solid black;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}

#mainContainer>div:last-child {
    border: solid black;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;

}

div.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

div.column {

    display: table-column;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border: solid black;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}

.row:last-child .column {border-bottom-style: solid}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">1 1</div>
        <div class="column">1 2</div>
        <div class="column">1 3</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">2 1</div>
        <div class="column">2 2</div>
        <div class="column">2 3</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">3 1</div>
        <div class="column">3 2</div>
        <div class="column">3 3</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-bottom` to `div.row:last-child .column`:

```
div.row:last-child .column {
  border-bottom: solid black;
}
```

```css
#mainContainer {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  border: solid black;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
}

#mainContainer>div:last-child {
  border: solid black;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
}

div.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

div.column {
  display: table-column;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  border: solid black;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
}

div.row:last-child .column {
  border-bottom: solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">1 1</div>
    <div class="column">1 2</div>
    <div class="column">1 3</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">2 1</div>
    <div class="column">2 2</div>
    <div class="column">2 3</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">3 1</div>
    <div class="column">3 2</div>
    <div class="column">3 3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/vYyBGmN

Answer (score 0):

you have put a

```
border-bottom-style: none
```

to your div.column

you can also remove all the style of the #mainContainer>div:last-child. it won't change anything

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve your problem as it has been already solved by others. Though a suggestion would be to leverage `display:grid` and following styling in your case. Will really reduce the nesting and css required.

```css
#mainContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  border-left: solid black;
  border-top: solid black;
}

div.cell {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-right: solid black;
  border-bottom: solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="cell">1 1</div>
        <div class="cell">1 2</div>
        <div class="cell">1 3</div>
        <div class="cell">2 1</div>
        <div class="cell">2 2</div>
        <div class="cell">2 3</div>
        <div class="cell">3 1</div>
        <div class="cell">3 2</div>
        <div class="cell">3 3</div>
</div>
```

You can even edit the no of `columns` by using JS like so:-

`` mainContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${columns},1fr)`; ``